# Fluentd TLS Encryption

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, encryption, fluentd, k3s

I am trying to understand where TLS fits in fluentd within input and output plugins? How can we achieve encryption on fluentd logs? I cannot find any example or use case on applying TLS with the tail input plugin and the file output plugin?
I am new to fluentd, recently deployed the daemonset on our k3s cluster, need some advice from the community.
Thanks

Comment: Please refer to the configuration of each respective plugin to verify whether it has TLS/encryption support or not. It depends on the plugin you choose to use. What do you mean by **achieving encryption on fluentd logs**? Do you mean the logs that the fluentd itself generates or the logs that it receives and sends? What is your exact use-case for this? Regarding in_tail and out_file plugins, [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) is not applicable in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Really appreciate it. We might have some application workload logs which include some sensitive data, I need some help in encryption techniques we can use for the logs which fluents receive and send? also, how can we apply encryption on logs in general.

Comment: Sure thing. Well, depending on the plugin you use, it may support `<transport>` section to configure TLS and the related configurations. Please refer to the docs for more details: https://docs.fluentd.org/configuration/transport-section.

Comment: Also, take a look at [fluent-plugin-encryption-filter](https://github.com/nidcode/fluent-plugin-encryption-filter). You can also visit thte list of plugins here: https://www.fluentd.org/plugins/all.

Comment: This is good info, I did explore the plug-ins list also got this recommendation from the fluent slack channel https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-sanitizer to use this. I am not sure how can deploy this plugin on Kubernetes, as I did add this plugin to the config file but soon after adding it my fluentd pod went to crashloopback state. I am new to fluentd, so in general how do we add any plugins to fluentd which as running as the daemonset on the kuberntes cluster ?

Comment: If a plugin is not part of the fluentd core then it needs to be first installed. See installation instructions here: https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-sanitizer#installation. So, you need to add the installation command in your Dockerfile (assuming you're using docker) to make sure it's there before fluentd process launches. With the version pinning, it would be like this: `sudo gem install fluent-plugin-sanitizer -v 0.1.1` with `RUN` in Dockerfile.

Comment: https://rubygems.org/gems/fluent-plugin-sanitizer/versions/0.1.1

Comment: Okay so all the third party plugins require a custom dockerfile build to run on Kubernetes, where can i find what all plugins are part of fluentd core ? Is all plugins listed on its documentation are referred to core ?

Comment: I believe so that all the listed ones in the docs are part of fluentd core. In addition, there's also a mention in the docs of such plugins like this: *It is included in Fluentd's core.*.

Comment: Ok got it. For instance, say i have to use any third-party plugin for my fluentd instance, do i need to build the image everytime by adding that plugin info to the Dockerfile ? 

Just for the matter of testing, I have added the below data to my fluentd config-map, but after restarting the daemonset the pod state went to crashloopbackoff, I am assuming this is because i don't have the respective plugin installed?


<filter **>
    @type sanitizer
    hash_salt mysalt
    <rule>
        keys ip
        pattern_ipv4 true
    </rule>

Comment: Depends on how you build the docker image. If docker layer is built once then that should do it. You don't have to do it again because that layer is cached. Regarding your crash, you should take a look at the logs e.g. `kubectl cluster-info dump`. Or, more specifically, just look at the logs of that specific pod/service using `kubectl logs` command.

Comment: I checked the fluentd logs, but no clue about the error. So I thought maybe it's the plugin issue, the daemonset works fine without adding the above filter to the config file.

Comment: There must be complete crash logs and the stacktrace of the error. How did you check that?

Comment: kubectl logs <podname>, see below the logs from the fluentdpod,

 /fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/fluentd-1.12.0/lib/fluent/config/basic_parser.rb:92:in `parse_error!': unmatched end tag at 02_filters.conf line 28,12 (Fluent::ConfigParseError)






added below in the config-map

  <filter **>
   @type sanitizer
   hash_salt mysalt
   <rule>
     keys ip
     pattern_ipv4 true
   <rule>
  </filter>

Comment: Right. And, did you test after installing the plugin?

Comment: I am new to this, not sure how to install a new plugin to a daemonset for Kubernetes, went through the documentation but unable to find any guidelines to add new plugins to the exiting config of the fluentd daemonset

Comment: Right. I think you can explore the existing docker images here: https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset/tree/master/docker-image. After building some understanding, you can create your own customized image with all the plugins you need and then use that.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate your inputs on this so far. My question is if we use fluentd as the logging solution for your Kubernetes cluster, what input plugins are relevant apart from tail plugin. I see on a lot of Kubernetes fluentd example, the input is set to tail to path /var/log/containers, so other inputs such as forward, HTTP, etc can also be used for the pods logs ?

Comment: You're welcome! It totally depends on the specific use-case. The `tail` you're seeing is for the container's logs itself. Depending on your architecture, there might be multiple input plugins e.g. http, forward, etc. along with tailing the container's logs.

Comment: Can i use http and forward plugins for the pods logs reason to check is tail plugin doesn't support tls ? Also tls can be applied to output plugins too, right ?

Comment: What do you mean by "pods' logs" here? Well, `tail` is just reading the local log file, there's no TLS here. If these logs are sent over to some destination that expects TLS then, yes, an output plugin that supports TLS can be used.

Comment: I mean when we deploy fluentd as daemon we use tail input plugin to read the logs from /var/log/containers.